# Convert native uint8_t (Java byte) into an int

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a native function (from a library) that does some work on **uint8_t** types (unsigned 8-bit number 0-255). The closest thing Java has is **byte** which must be signed.

How can I convert this **byte** into a proper positive integer to use in Java? I know I'll have to store it in a **short** or **int** in order to properly represent numbers from 0-255, but I don't know how to convert the **byte**.

I tried `int intValue = byteValue & 0xFF;`, but that is giving me unexpected results, so I suspect it's incorrect. Or that is correct and I am misunderstanding the expected results from the native library function. Would appreciate confirmation either way.

Comment: What you've tried is correct. You should check the results from the native library carefully, and edit your question with the actual results and expected ones.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I need for now. Will need to dig into the documentation and code some more to figure this out then.

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, I have your same problem, did you come up with a solution? Anyway, your attempt seems returning me right values

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use a Guava library function to convert a byte to an int, treating it as unsigned: [UnsignedBytes.toInt](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html#toInt-byte-). So, if you returned the value of a C++ unsigned value as a byte to Java, you can then fix it up.

If you want to make it into an int and then return it to java as an int, that should be perfectly straightforward.